# How do i call an activity after a sms has been received by application?

Tags: android

I am using BroadcastReceiver class for receiving the sms. My main class code is:

```
package org.apache.sms;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;


public class SMSApp extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";        
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /*
        Intent i = new Intent(context,Second.class);
        i.putExtra("msg",str);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
        context.startActivity(i);
        */

    }
    this.abortBroadcast();
}
```

}

manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.apache.sms" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name=".SMSApp">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
</uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Right now my application displays the message in a pop up.

But i want to display the second screen when my application receive the sms. For this i have added following code after Toast.makeText method :

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context,Second.class);
        i.putExtra("msg",str);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
        context.startActivity(i);
```

After adding following code nothing is happening. No error only message comes in notification bar.

Comment: can u post your updated code?

Comment: thank saurabh for replying i have added my updated code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should add 'Second' Activity in manifest file?

Comment: Thanks pixel & jn0101 it was due to the activity tag (second) that was missing in manifest file. Added <activity android:name="Second" class=".second" android:label="SMSApp">
      </activity> tag and it resolved the issue.